# How display content from an uploaded file onto a form

Tags: forms

I am using managed_file form element to upload a file on my custom form in Drupal 7, and I was wondering if its possible to process the file and display its contents on the form for nspection prior to submiting the form.

Something along these lines:

-User uploads a file, (its in binary format a the minute but just for simplicity suppose it a csv file.

-Process the input file and display the contents of the file to the user on the form so they can inspect the data.

-If the user is happy with the data procced with the form submission.

Is a custom file validator the best place to call my method for extracting the data from the file? and how do I then update the form to display a table containing the extracted data.

I appreceiate any ideas or pointers.

Thanks.

sample code:

```
<?php

  function custom_validator($file)
  {
      $errors = array();
      $destination = "public://SessionFiles/";
      $file->destination = file_destination($destination.$file->filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

      $scriptFile = '/c:/wamp/www/sandbox/python/DatReader.py';
      exec('python '.$scriptFile. ' '.$filePath .' '.'2>&1' , $output, $return);

      if($return == 0) //script executed succesfully
      {
         return $output; // return the data from teh python script. 
      }

      return array(); //script failed return empty array.
  }


  custom_module_form($form, $formState)
  {
      $form['dataFile'] = array
      (
          '#type'              => 'managed_file',
          '#title'             => t('Upload Data File'),
          '#upload_validators' => array
          (          
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('dat'),
            'custom_validator'         => array(),
          ),
         '#upload_location'   => 'public://SessionFiles',   
       );


       return $form;

  }
```